How can Stack Exchange prove a violation to the Data Dump download agreement?
In the last few weeks there has been lot of talks about the new Data Dump process. From people asking if the dumps are watermarked to people pointing out that the user agreement for the download conditions is not stored, that the dump formats have been a violation to the CC license till the start of times (quickly shoved under the rug with an emergency update... that probably changes nothing for users wanting to revoke the license) or even arguing about the legality of the process itself... the  list goes on, and on, and on.
The current Data Dump download process contains a threat from the company. The users has to agree to the following terms to be able to download the file

I understand that this file is being provided to me for my own use and for projects that do not include training a large language model (LLM), and that should I distribute this file for the purpose of LLM training, Stack Overflow reserves the right to decline to allow me access to future downloads of this data dump

This intent has been confirmed by the company words which multiple time expressed is willingness to block the access to the dump for users who don't comply to their request.
What follows is not about the legal or ethical aspect of the issue of implementing additional terms to the download of the file.
Today, I am asking HOW the company intends to police its very own threat.
What tools has Stack Exchange to be able to prove that any user has indeed utilized a specific version of the data dump file they download from the site (thus agreeing to their terms) and not ... any other existing compilation of the site content including but not limited to other derivative products that other unrelated users crafted by extracting the data from their own copy of the dump and republishing the CC contents under a different format?
How would the company go to justify blocking the access to the data dump to our proverbial "Average Joe" who just released a Stack Overflow LLM demo on Hugging Face? Would they just assume that since they downloaded a dump five months ago that dump must be the file they used, despite any Creative Common content being FREELY REPRODUCIBLE IN ANY FORMAT and thus the origin of the data being something they CAN'T PROVE? (I hope they aren't crazy enough that they think they can just poison the data source...).
Any user could download the site specific dump for the site they have an account on for their personal use... but then use a different larger post processed aggregate dataset to train a LLM and that would NOT violate the agreed terms even if that dataset was obtained by merging the individual site dumps the company provided. Once again, the Creative Common license is VIRAL. Perhaps it is time the company gets this small, insignificant detail?
But we don't even have to come to that because... how can the Company even prove that "GuybrushThePirate" who distributed the file on Hugging Face is indeed "MrBrown - Save the Data Dump" who downloaded the dump a month ago? Do they expect users to be readily recognizable for them on the web? Do they plan to ask Google if their tracking cookies on the site have farmed some data about them? ... Even proving any specific user trained a LLM seems hard, without even considering they also need to prove they used a specific data dump file.
Unless Stack doesn't want to rely solely on 'self-admission', which coincidentally was what they planned to do for AI generated content moderation in the past...
Jokes aside, I don't see how the company can back up any claim that an user used the specific version of the dump they got after agreeing to the "no LLM training usage" terms to train a LLM - unless the users themself confirms that.
To be blunt, I am perfectly aware that the usual, average standard vexatious Terms of Services any company uses contain catch all lines like...

Stack Overflow reserves the right to refuse, suspend or terminate your access to the public Network if it determines, in its sole discretion, that you have in any way violated these Public Network Terms or are otherwise ineligible to access or use the Network or Services. If your actions are determined by us to violate these Public Network Terms, Stack Overflow may, in its sole discretion, try to remediate that violation by working with you individually, but is under no obligation to do so, and if any such remediation efforts are unsuccessful (in Stack Overflow’s sole discretion), then Stack Overflow may revoke your rights to the Network

which basically serve to be able to ban anyone, anytime without any need for explanation or proof that they violated a term other that the company own "discretion", but I don't think they little trust the company still have would survive going down that path.  Despite the ability for the company to ban/ suspend / restrict any user on a whim, I don't think that a second Monica scandal will be very "healthy" for them and could easily spell the end for the site.
Based on the above, I hope that any attempt the company will make to restrict any users in the future won't be based on some generic smoke and mirror "we know, trust me bro'" approach. I am therefore asking what is the plan they intend to follow to ensure any attempt at putting those threats into practice doesn't look as a personal user shaming campaign made out of spite or an arbitrary unfounded claim to their own gain.
How does Stack Exchange intend to prove that a specific file was used to train a LLM when the content of the file is freely reproducible under CC in an ethical, believable and plausible way?


How does Stack Exchange intend to prove that a specific file was used to train a LLM when the content of the file is freely reproducible under CC?


If there are no watermarks in the data dumps: not possible (currently, there seems to be no watermarks).
If there are watermarks in the data dumps: SE could try using techniques such as this one.

Hence the importance of users sharing data dump hashes, and if different, diffing dumps to spot and clean watermarks.
Note that adding watermarks to CC BY-SA texts could mess up the attribution requirements if not done properly (and properly may mean making these watermarks rather obvious, i.e. useless).

How can Stack Exchange ethically enforce their threat regarding the Data Dump usage?

One cannot ethically enforce an unethical threat.

Even with watermarking (HOW can you watermark the actual question text without de facto editing some content that is also owned by the original poster? By doing so you are creating a false attribution too) they would still have no way to prove that the user was the one who trained the file, unless they admit it in the first place... +1 for the interesting article btw

In theory - you could add in a question, answer, post or other content like they do with maps. In practice, I suspect this would make the dumps unsustainably expensive

There's plenty of data in the data dump that isn't CC BY-SA that could be used for watermarking purposes without any impact to the content license. The entire Votes.xml or Badges.xml, adding XML comments to any file, or metadata. Just because the content was used also doesn't mean the data dump was used - it very well could have been manually copied from the web interface, for example. This seems like an empty threat to discourage law and contract abiding companies to pay for OverflowAPI but does nothing to actually stop anything.

@JourneymanGeek Agreed. In that case, we could check if the user who "posted" the watermark exists.

@SPArcheon-onstrike yes, that'd mess up the the attribution requirements https://law.stackexchange.com/q/104328/31

@ThomasOwens true but watermarks outside the text used for LLM training won't be useful to detect if LLM was trained on the dump. We definitely need to check for such watermarks too though if someone shares the file. I agree it's likely just an empty threat. (And since genAI companies don't hesitate to train on large datasets regardless of the license, some CC BY-SA content is going to appear as very safe, even if behind some decorative checkbox).

@FranckDernoncourt To be clear, I also think they have no reasonable way to enforce the threat. But since Monica clearly showed the company doesn't need to be reasonable to smear someone, I prefer to make them realize their position before someone goes for M.A.D.
